# In Snowflake, how to derive the last 365 days for all dates in Date Dimension table

Tags: date, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

My date dimension table has a column "date_id" which has dates from 2016-01-01 till 2025-01-01. I wanted to create a view on the top of this date table and introduce an extra column say "date_id_365". The new column should have **ALL** the last 365 dates for each date_id.

Like for example If I pick a date_id to say 2020-01-15, that date_id should return dates from 2019-01-15 till 2020-01-15.

How to write the SQL in snowflake for this?

Answer (score 1):

I think maybe you're looking for something like this...which is pretty standard SQL, not specifically for Snowflake.  This assumes that date_id is a DATE field, which I'm not seeing in your comments, but you could convert it or use the date field.

```
SELECT a.date_id, b.date_id as date_id_365
FROM dim_date a
JOIN dim_date b
  ON b.date_id BETWEEN DATEADD(year,-1,a.date_id) AND a.date_id
```

I haven't tested this myself, but pretty sure this will work for you.  The only issue will be with your dates for the year 2016, since it won't have any dates in 2015 to join back to.

Comment: Thanks!! This is something I found in snowflake community  WITH CTE_MY_DATE AS (
   SELECT DATEADD(DAY,-1*SEQ4(), CURRENT_DATE()) AS MY_DATE
    FROM TABLE(GENERATOR(ROWCOUNT=>365))